# Do password expiry rules reducing the security of the system?

Tags: security, password, best-practices, password-policy

**The problem**

I regularly have a debate with my CTO which usually begins something like this ...

```
CTO: My password expired, that should never happen. 
Me : It's a security risk to never expire passwords. 
CTO: It's a security risk to force passwords to be reset because users have bad habits. 
Me : Yes but the security is in the user not the system, enforcing password expiry ensures the system is secure in the event of an unknown breach of the userbase.
```

This raises an interesting question that neither of us primarily not being a system administrator but being a position that we need to apply a policy to this effect don't really agree on what the right answer should be.

**My standing**

The system is more secure if you force all users to change their passwords in X amount of time where X is computed by determining the algorithm strength used to protect the password and an estimated time to break (with brute force) the raw value back in to the original password.

**CTO's Standing**

The act of forcing users to change their passwords all the time results in patterns / ****123 "like" patterns over time or users write passwords down meaning the users "bad habit" is more of a risk to the system than the data being compromised in some more technical manner (e.g. through brute forcing).

**So I would like to know**

Is there some way I can prove either way weather or not we should enforce a password reset policy based on some industry best practice?

***OR***

Is one of us just plain wrong?

Comment: It's Linux or Windows environment?

Comment: It applies to both I would say ... it's more general to managing passwords. Do you see password management as needing different treatment depending on the domain type / server environment? I figured the key was the practices not the specifics (e.g. exactly how the password is stored isn't relevant it's a question of how best to look after it) in this case.

Comment: I note that the latest version of the NIST guidelines on the subject recommend NOT expiring passwords without a good reason. https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: A great read ... some really interesting stuff in there thanks @Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CTO is more right, but it's a more complex issue. NIST ( https://csrc.nist.gov/ ) is probably the "industry best practices" reference.

When it comes to passwords length, not complexity or frequent changes, is the way to go. ( https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/ ) They suggest phrashes or sentences rather than a single word.

You describe  hashing passwords before storing them which is the logically better alternative than plain text. The problem is with multi-gpu systems tens to hundreds of hashes can be calculated and checked per second.

The links below discuss the changes. I'd suggest paying special attention to salting passwords before they're hashed.

https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/

https://www.passwordping.com/surprising-new-password-guidelines-nist/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216998/updating-password-hashing-without-forcing-a-new-password-for-existing-users

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it increases security risks if you don't force passwords to expire.

As your CTO said, because we have bad habits, passwords will eventually leak one way or another, e.g. type the password in the user input field, leave it unencrypted in some application config file, etc.

Forcing users to change passwords reinforces security in terms of availability, a leaked password that expires in 15 days will force the attacker to take advantage of it in the next 2 weeks, whereas a permanent password will leave a door open to external danger.

If you see this from the attacker's point of view as well, it's pretty deterring to know you may be able to sniff a password after several weeks stealing data only to see that halfway that process all those passwords changed and you have to start over.

Sometimes the best way to make your system harder to crack isn't to make it more robust, but rather to avoid harm altogether by letting people know they'll waste their time.

To me it looks like you have a lazy CTO who doesn't want to come up with new passwords.

Comment: I think your threat model is way off base. Hostiles don't get passwords by slowly sniffing, you get them by by phishing. And then you immediately use them to get what you want, or you implant malware that makes the password irrelevant to you.

Comment: @MichaelKohne You are talking about a different case scenario. Password expiry policies have nothing to do with directly stealing a password and using it, which is out of the question context.

Comment: To sum it up, passwords expiry policies limit the time frame when identity theft works, attack vectors are blocked through other means if the need arises.

Comment: Except that in most modern cases the hostile doesn't NEED to maintain the credentials. They either do their dirty work immediately, or they implant something so they can get back in even if you change the password. With the exception of very high value target (who should be using MFA anyway), it's pointless.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I still don't know where you get your logic, password expiry policies are there for the same reason you have a key lock at home. You don't want to get robbed by every single person you come across, but you definitely won't stop James Bond from stealing your data. You seem to assume the only attack vector is directly stealing someone's credentials, while this protects you passively over time. Long story short, enforce regular password expiry policies.

Comment: but password expiry has long been shown to lead to users using crappy passwords. I'm not saying never on password expiry, but I will say that in most situations, the fact that it causes bad password practices on the part of your users more than outweighs the extra security of changing the passwords. And honestly, if it's that important, then you should be doing MFA anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it is not easy.

Currently (the situation was probably different when the question was asked initially) the time needed to brute force a "bad" password (for example a single dictionary word made "safe" by some usual substitution rules) is much shorter than any time span you'd consider for password expiry, at least if the database of password hashes is available.

On the other hand, cracking a "good" password (like 16 true random alphanumeric characters) is still beyond being cracked within a few years unless your attacker has a REAL BIG budget. And if you are up against big players, standard passwords are probably not an option for you anyway.

Many other issues, like the "bad user habits" already mentioned also apply.

Another thing to consider is that expiring passwords also lead to loss in productivity and additional costs/work for IT support.

So, IMHO, a better choice than meddling with passwords expiry nowadays may be to invest in hardware for password safes, biometric/smart card-based or other two-factor authentication methods...

But, usually you won't get an ultimate answer without hiring someone who does a very detailed analysis of your requirements, your risks and your possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong and your CTO is right.

Enforcing password changes will annoy users into evading the security. This causes obvious security flaws like:

1. Post-it's on monitors with passwords written on them.
2. a suffixed counter at the password (for example, password1 turns into password2 - and if you can detect that, then you've got REAL BIG problems, as you're storing passwords in plain text.)

Do note that option 2) here directly counters your security argument about unknown breaches of security. If an attack figures out that your password was "password124", he WILL attempt "password125". Along with any other common mutations.

For more details about good password management, see also [guidelines](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#memsecretver) of entities such as the US government:

> Verifiers SHOULD NOT require memorized secrets to be changed arbitrarily (e.g., periodically). However, verifiers SHALL force a change if there is evidence of compromise of the authenticator.

Translated into non-technical, that means that Expiration == bad, but if you have reasonable cause to believe that the users' password is leaked, you enforce it on a case-by-case basis. Or global if your entire users table leaked.

See also [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4704/218173) on Security.se.